# How to parse/create a dynamic url in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to create a buildURL function that can generate an url. However I have run into a problem when facing a dynamic url.

```
type ShopifyDownloader struct {
    Domain      string
    AccessToken string
}

func (sd *ShopifyDownloader) BuildURL(Path string, Query map[string]string) (string, error) {
    u, err := url.Parse("https://123.myshopify.com/admin/orders/count.json?access_token=123")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot parse", err)
        return "", err
    }
    u.Host = sd.Domain
    u.Path = Path
    params := url.Values{}
    for key, value := range Query {
        params.Add(key, value)
    }
    u.RawQuery = params.Encode()
    nu := u.String()
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString(nu)
    buffer.WriteString("?access_token=")
    buffer.WriteString(sd.AccessToken)
    bu := buffer.String()
    return bu, err
}
```

It takes domain, token, path and queries and generate an url in string. However it does not work with a dynamic path (with id) like 
this /admin/orders/#{id}.json or this /admin/products/#{id}/images/#{id}.json
Does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: Please check the help section. A good question shows us what you've tried yourself. ATM, this question might as well be a request for others to write your solution for you. In which case, check the source of projects like [gorilla mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#examples) and the like, they already implement something very similar to what you're looking for

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What do you expect to happen? There's nothing there that would handle any sort of token like `#{id}`.

Comment: @JimB sorry I mean I dont know how to do it the #{id}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just build a url with something simpler at the point where you use it?

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/admin/orders/count.json?access_token=%s&custom=%s",sd.Domain,sd.Token,customparam)
```

Then use it. This has the virtue of being completely clear as to intent and the url used in each case while sharing the important stuff (shopify domain etc). Then for your question about ids it becomes easier:

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/admin/orders/%d.json?access_token=%s",sd.Domain,orderID,sd.Token)
```

and

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/admin/products/%d/images/%d.json?access_token=%s",sd.Domain,productID,imageID,sd.Token)
```

if you feel your params are super complex (for me this would have to be at least 5), just put them in an url.Values (including the token):

```
params := url.Values{"myparam":{"123"}, "token": {sd.Token}}
url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/admin/orders/count.json?%s", sd.Domain, 
params.Encode())
```

but this is only worthwhile if you have a significant number of params.

If you want to add functions to ShopifyDownloader, why force the caller to define the url structure? Try to make it simpler for them. You don't need to parse urls or write to a bytes buffer, http.Get expects a string, so work with strings. If you want to build functions, consider instead having separate functions which know about the url formats, to abstract this away from the caller, so :

```
 func (sd *ShopifyDownloader) OrderURL(orderID int, params url.Values) string {
        params["token"] = []string{sd.AccessToken}
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s/admin/orders/%d.json?%s",sd.Domain,orderID,params)
    }
```

The caller should not know about the specific format of Shopify urls, which may change (just as the endpoint may change).

Comment: I tried this way at first but it would not accounted for numerous query the url might have. For example if the url like https://123.myshopify.com/admin/orders/count.json?product_id=345&collection_id=567&access_token=123 then the fmt.Sprintf would not work

Comment: I've given you an example above. Sprintf would of course work, you just need to put the params in. You could put this in a separate function if you prefer. I'd work with strings at this point, not bytes, this is not data. You do not need to parse urls in order to print them, just output a string, which is what http.Client expects for the url.